# Forms con Post independientes

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios, post

Estimados tengo la siguiente duda es posible realizar el siguiente código? he tratado de varias formas poder generar una especie de post recursivo, es decir, necesito consultar en la misma pagina si el rut esta o no en una tabla y después guardar la información en otra tabla, no se si sera posible de esta forma, agradecería cualquier comentario

```
                  <form id='form_feed_buscar' name="form_feed_buscar" action='ayuda_buen_pagador.php'  method="POST">
                      <b> Rut: </b>
                      <input type="text" name="rut" id="rut" title="INGRESE RUT SIN GUION" />
                      <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info" name="btn2">
                      <br><br>
                      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        
                        <tbody>
                          <?php
                          if(isset($_POST['btn2'])){                                  
                            $rut = $_POST['rut'];
                            $where="";
                            $existe = 0;
                            $where="where rut = '".$rut."'";
                            
                            $sql=$db->prepare("select * from buen_pagador $where ");
                            $sql->execute();                                    
                            while($row = $sql->fetch()){
                              $existe++; 
                            }
                            if($existe==0) {echo "<br> <b> NO SE ENCONTRARON COINCIDENCIAS CON LOS DATOS INGRESADOS <br>";}

                            if ($existe>0) {
                              ?>
                                
                                <div class="separador">
                                    <p><strong>Formulario de activación</strong></p>
                                </div>
                                <form id='form_feed_guardarr' name="form_feed_guardarr" action='guardar_buen_pagador.php' method="POST" >
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                      <div class="col-md-9">                                    
                                        <span class="help-block">Rut</span>                                                   
                                        <span class="help-block-info col-md-12" id="Rut" name="Rut"><?php echo $rut ?> </span>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <br>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">                                            
                                      <div class="form-group">                                              
                                          <div class="col-md-9">                                          
                                              <span class="help-block">Indique linea a reactivar</span>
                                              <input type="text" id="primera_linea" name="primera_linea" class="form-control" placeholder=""   />
                                              
                                          </div>
                                      </div>                                       
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">                                            
                                      <div class="form-group">                                              
                                          <div class="col-md-9">                                          
                                              <span class="help-block">segunda linea a reactivar</span>
                                              <input type="text" id="segunda_linea" name="segunda_linea" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                                          </div>
                                      </div>                                       
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">                                            
                                      <div class="form-group">                                              
                                          <div class="col-md-9">                                          
                                              <span class="help-block">tercera linea a reactivar</span>
                                              <input type="text" id="tercera_linea" name="tercera_linea" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                                          </div>
                                      </div>                                       
                                  </div>
                                  <br>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">                                            
                                      <div class="form-group">                                              
                                          <div class="col-md-9">                                          
                                              <span class="help-block">cuarta linea a reactivar</span>
                                              <input type="text" id="cuarta_linea" name="cuarta_linea" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                                          </div>
                                      </div>                                       
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-3">
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                          <div class="col-md-9">
                                              <span class="help-block">motivo que lo solicita</span>
                                              <select class="form-control select" id="motivo" name="motivo" >
                                                  <option value=""> </option>
                                                  <option value="pago_no_reflejado">Pago no reflejado</option>
                                                  <option value="No_puedo_pagar_hoy_pago_manana">No puedo pagar hoy pago mañana</option>
                                                  <option value="problemas_economicos">Problemas económicos</option>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 100%  ;height:50px;"></div>
                                  <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" name="guardar" style="margin-right: 45px;">Guardar</button>
                                  
                                </form>

                              <?php
                            }
                          }
                          ?>  
                        </tbody>
                      </table>                     
                    </form>
```

o como seria posible ejecutar dos post en haciendo llamado a actions distintas?, uno seria la consulta del rut y el otro el guardar información que dentro de la base, en base a que si se encuentra el rut dentro de la primera consulta, estaré atento a cualquier apoyo o comentario

Comment: Puedes usar un solo formulario con dos botones (en caso de que los datos a enviar para los dos action sean los mismos) y diferenciar, según el botón que haya sido presionado, qué action debe ejecutarse en el servidor. Si los datos son distintos entonces es mejor usar dos formularios distintos.

Answer (score 1):

No es posible utilizar un `<form>` dentro de otro. Deben estar totalmente separados y no anidados.

> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element

Debes considerar reorganizar los formularios para que no se traslapen. De esta manera tambien pueden actuar totalmente independientes, con `action` distintos. Dependiendo de lo que deseas lograr, puedes simplemente finalizar el primer formulario antes:

```
<form id='form_feed_buscar' name="form_feed_buscar" action='ayuda_buen_pagador.php' method="POST">
    <b> Rut: </b>
    <input type="text" name="rut" id="rut" title="INGRESE RUT SIN GUION" />
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-info" name="btn2">
</form>
<br><br>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">

    <tbody>
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['btn2'])){                                  
          $rut = $_POST['rut'];
          $where="";
          $existe = 0;
          $where="where rut = '".$rut."'";
          
          $sql=$db->prepare("select * from buen_pagador $where ");
          $sql->execute();                                    
          while($row = $sql->fetch()){
            $existe++; 
          }
          if($existe==0) {echo "<br> <b> NO SE ENCONTRARON COINCIDENCIAS CON LOS DATOS INGRESADOS <br>";}

          if ($existe>0) {
            ?>

        <div class="separador">
            <p><strong>Formulario de activación</strong></p>
        </div>
        <form id='form_feed_guardarr' name="form_feed_guardarr" action='guardar_buen_pagador.php' method="POST">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <span class="help-block">Rut</span>
                        <span class="help-block-info col-md-12" id="Rut" name="Rut"><?php echo $rut ?> </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <span class="help-block">Indique linea a reactivar</span>
                        <input type="text" id="primera_linea" name="primera_linea" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <span class="help-block">segunda linea a reactivar</span>
                        <input type="text" id="segunda_linea" name="segunda_linea" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <span class="help-block">tercera linea a reactivar</span>
                        <input type="text" id="tercera_linea" name="tercera_linea" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <span class="help-block">cuarta linea a reactivar</span>
                        <input type="text" id="cuarta_linea" name="cuarta_linea" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <span class="help-block">motivo que lo solicita</span>
                        <select class="form-control select" id="motivo" name="motivo">
                            <option value=""> </option>
                            <option value="pago_no_reflejado">Pago no reflejado</option>
                            <option value="No_puedo_pagar_hoy_pago_manana">No puedo pagar hoy pago mañana</option>
                            <option value="problemas_economicos">Problemas económicos</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3" style="width: 100%  ;height:50px;"></div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="submit" name="guardar"
                style="margin-right: 45px;">Guardar</button>

        </form>

        <?php
          }
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```